# Tricky formula to find common ratio of geometric progression

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, alternative-proof

Suppose $a_1,a_2,a_3,...$ are in an arithmetic sequence ($d\neq 0)$ . If $a_3,a_{13},a_{63}$ are geometric sequence ,find common ratio of geometric sequence .

There is an ordinary method to solve this problem like below 
$$\quad{\frac{a_{13}}{a_3}=\frac{a_{63}}{a_{13}}=q\\
\frac{a_{13}-a_3}{a_3}=\frac{a_{63}-a_{13}}{a_{13}}\\
\frac{10d}{a_3}=\frac{50d}{a_{13}}\\\frac{10\not d}{a_3}=\frac{50 \not d}{a_{13}}\\
\frac{1}{a_1+2d}=\frac{5}{a_1+12d}\\5a_1+10d=a_1+12d\\4a_1=2d\\2a_1=d \to \\q=\frac{a_{13}}{a_3}=\frac{a_1+12d}{a_1+2d}=\frac{25d}{5d}=5}$$ 
$Now$ :tricky way 
$$q=\color{red} {\frac{63-13}{13-3}=\frac{50}{10}=5}$$ My question is : How can prove this tricky method ?

Comment: BTW, you don't need the second half of the calculation: once you've canceled the $d$, you have the ratio.

Answer (score 4):

There is no trick:

$$ q= {a_{13}\over a_3} = {(q-1)a_{13}\over (q-1)a_3} ={a_{63}-a_{13}\over a_{13}-a_3}={50d\over 10d}$$

Comment: Writing the same thing with general indices, one can say that if $a_k,a_m,a_n$ are from an arithmetic progression and are in geometric progression, $q=\frac {n-m}{m-k}$.  It is not specific to $3,13,63$.  It is not clear to me whether OP was claiming this.

Comment: Yes, nice observation.

Answer (score 1):

Some hints:$$a_n = a_0 + dn$$

$$a_{63} - a_{13} = (a_0 + 63d) - (a_0 + 13d) = 50d$$

$$\frac{a_{63} - a_{13}}{a_{13} - a_3} = \frac{50d}{10d} = 5$$